# Why can a defensive lineman wear a number in the 60s?

Tags: american-football, nfl

[Leonard Williams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Williams_%28American_football%29), a defensive end, wears number 62 for the Jets.

**Why can a defensive lineman wear a number in the 60s?** My understanding was that 62 was for an offensive guard.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this chart](http://football.about.com/cs/football101/a/bl_numbersystem.htm), the number 62 is designated for Offensive Line and Defensive Line.  As Leonard Williams is a Defensive Lineman, he is more than welcome to wear #62.

> 1-9 Quarterbacks and Kickers
>
> 10-19 Quarterbacks, Receivers, Tight Ends, and Kickers
>
> 20-49 Running Backs and Defensive Backs
>
> 50-59 Centers and Linebackers
>
> **60-79 Defensive Linemen and Offensive Linemen**
>
> 80-89 Receivers and Tight Ends (or 40-49 if those ranges are taken)
>
> 90-99 Defensive Linemen and Linebackers

His college number of 94 is currently being worn by [Damon Harrison](http://www.newyorkjets.com/team/roster/Damon-Harrison/19c33ca4-9bf3-47cc-9117-42f4ad449024), also a Defensive Lineman.